# Project Lombok @Slf4j external configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, slf4j, lombok

so I'am writing simple Spring Boot(version 1.56) Application. And started using Project lombok, specifically@Slf4j feature for logging. Logging works fine, but how can I configure this logger? To be precise I want to be able to change logging level using external file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `lombok`, it is about `slf4j` configuration. It should be done by updating your `application.properties` file.

You can check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-levels) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration)

Comment: to add, set root logging level by `logging.level.root=WARN`