# Lombok sl4fj: How to change console logger lvl

Tags: logging, lombok

I started to work on a bot for binance treading. I am using [this wrapper library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.webcerebrium/binance-api/1.0.7).

This wrapper is using:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
```

for logging it looks like this in code:

```
@Slf4j
@Data
public class BinanceApi {
...
}
```

Right now it is displaying a lot of information that I don´t want to be displayed. I want to  change `consoleAppender` level for displaying only error level logs.

I have found this [Project Lombok @Slf4j external configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222068/project-lombok-slf4j-external-configuration)

But it's not helping me.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Adrian, welcome to SO. Please make the effort and proofread and format you questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log level for the output is not configured with Lombok, but with the used logging framework. SLF4J is a facade for Java logging frameworks. This is the explanation from  https://www.slf4j.org/

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks (e.g. java.util.logging, logback, log4j) allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time.

To change the output log level, you have to figure out which of the logging frameworks is used and then look up on how to configure the log level for that log framework. Starting points could be the dependencies of the project or existing logging configurations.

Comment: See, so propably i just need to add S4lfj and configurate it

Comment: Binance is using Logback, see https://github.com/webcerebrium/java-binance-api/blob/master/build.gradle#L46 , and thus you likely inherit this and have to configure the output logging level in Logback, see https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html For example, by adding a `logback.xml` to your classpath that limits the output log level: ...  <root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root> ...