# show debug level logs in console using slf4j without knowing logger implementation

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, java-ee-8

I am using Lombok's @Slf4j annotation to get logger and log some data. I am NOT USING Spring boot application.yml. So, how can I show debug level logs in the console now? How should it be configured?

Is there any way not to use implementation-specific configuration property?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222068/project-lombok-slf4j-external-configuration

Comment: @jr593 , no! I don't use spring boot.